# Can VS2010 show me which header file pulls in a declaration?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, include

I have a header file in a mixed C/C++ project, call it `A.h`, that uses a type declared in another header file, say `X.h`. `A.h` does not include `X.h` directly, but includes other header files that, themselves, include *other* header files, etc., that eventually include `X.h`.

I'd like to know which of the header files included by `A.h` are indirectly responsible for pulling in this type declaration from `X.h`, without manually recursively inspecting the entire hierarchy of header files myself.

Can Visual Studio 2010 show me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a compiler option that allows you to see which headers are included and when.

It's `/showIncludes` and you can find it in the advanced project properties.

Comment: Unfortunately it's very, very hard to actually use this information. The header file I'm interested in ends up several hundred lines below the original (what with all the MS SDK and Boost headers), and there's no way to fold this list.

Comment: @detly you can try to remove the header from the hard drive temporarily. The first point of inclusion will be signaled (`file not found, attempted to include in X.h`) or similar.

Comment: That won't necessarily work though - it might error out on some other compilation unit long before it gets to `A.h` (which, in this case, it does).